# Build Error with NuGet packages

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am currently trying to set up this structure of Projects:

- Core (.Net Standard)

  - References: MVVMLightLibsStd10
  - References: ...
- Desktop (.Net Framework 4.6.1)

  - References: MVVMLightLibsStd10
  - References: ...

When I compile this locally, it works fine but on the Build-Server I get the Error

```
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GalaSoft' could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

for each time that I reference any of the Nuget packages.

Project can be found [here](https://github.com/lightlike/DSACharacterSheet)

Build-Log is [here](https://pastebin.com/pv4NGKHL)

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [**MvvmLightLibs**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs) NuGet package into your DSACharacterSheet.Desktop project.

In the `App.xaml.cs` file, you specified to use below namespaces:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Views;
```

But they can not be found based on the installed packages. After install `MvvmLightLibs` package, the namespaces will be valid, and you can build the project successful.

Comment: I already did that by installing MvvmLightLibsStd10. That is the .Net Standard-Version of MvvmLight. But if that was the case wouldn't it be the same on my local computer and not just on the Build Server?

Comment: But when I got your source code locally, it showed above namespaces invalid on your local machine. After install MvvmLightLibs packages, it can build successful both in local machine and the build server. So you can install the package and build again to check the result.

Comment: MvvmLightLibs did not work as it threw an error when starting. My error was, that I had some Visual Studio temprary files that made it work on my PC but not on the Build Server. I cleaned those up and it worked after some tinkering.